# Dynamic content in all page in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, sitemesh

I am developing my site in Spring MVC with Sitemesh. [image: Here is example]

Dynamic content is changed oon every page, Menu and Footer I can include in template definition. But there comes a problem. On every site below the dynamic content there should be a news list with loaded some news from my DB. I created my @Controller and it loads 5 latest news, but how to add this on my template? What request mapping should implement my news controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't kwow how Sitemesh works, but I solved problems like that by using interceptor:

create a class that extends : **HandlerInterceptorAdapter**

Override the method **postHandle** and populate the modelAndView Object like this :

```
modelAndView.addObject("newslist",myNewsList);
```

So you will have a variable **$newslist** injected into all your views.

Don't forget to declare bean in your mvc-congig.xml :

```
<bean id="newsListInterceptor" class="mypackage.NewsListInterceptor"/>
```

As the interceptor is executed for each request I also use ehcache to store the result and avoid during a select in database for each call.